# Edit MaxRequestLen in FastCGI on IIS (Plesk)

Tags: php, iis, file-upload, windows-server-2008, fastcgi

I am receiving a 500 Internal Server Error when trying to upload large files on my server. All of my PHP settings are correct, i.e. post_max_size, execution_time etc...

I am pretty certain it is a restriction with FastCGI as that is what most websites are telling me. However, all of these websites are referring to servers running Apache, and therefore the fix is simple (just edit the conf file). As I am running IIS, the problem is a little more complicated!

Does anybody have any idea how I can edit the 'MaxRequestLen' value for FastCGI in IIS? I cannot seem to find a way to do it, not helped by the fact that I am not very familiar with IIS.

**If this is not the issue, then please suggest other causes of the problem uploading large files with IIS and FastCGI**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at this question for hours, and after a lot of fiddling around on the server with configurations etc, it turned out to be a bug in PHP. The bug has been reported here:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63330

Anybody wanting to see an explanation of the bug and what caused this issue, please refer to:

[PHP Upload - 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007906/php-upload-500-internal-server-error)